# How to insert a new tag between every two v-for produced tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Is there a way I can insert new tag between every two v-for produced tags?
Like `Array.join()`.

#### Background:

I want to insert a `<span>,</span>` between every two `<router-link></router-link>`.

`<router-link></router-link>` is produced by `v-for`, the code like this:

```
<router-link tag="a" 
             v-for="text in ['vue', 'react', 'JQuery']"
             :key="text"
>
  {{ text }} &nbsp;
</router-link>
```

Run it and seems like this:

`vue react JQuery`

I don't know how to directly insert `<span>,</span>` between these so I move it into a `<div>`:

```
<div v-for="text in ['vue', 'react', 'JQuery']"
     :key="text">
   <router-link tag="a">
    {{ text }}
  </router-link>
  <span>,&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Run it  and seems like this:

`vue, react, JQuery,`

so the question is that the last ‘,’ is redundant.
I can fix it by `v-show`:

```
<div v-for="(text, index) in ['vue', 'react', 'JQuery']"
     :key="text">
   <router-link tag="a">
    {{ text }}
  </router-link>
  <span v-show="index !== 2">,&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

It works nice, but I want to know is there a easy way to do this?

Thanks response.

Answer (score 4):

Your last approach is the way to go, but you should probably use `Array.length` for processing the last occurrence, in case the array changes.

```
<span v-show="index !== (items.length - 1)">,&nbsp;</span>
```

**Or use plain CSS** (notice I'm adding class `route` on the `div` element):

```
div.route:not(:last-child) > a::after {
  content: ',';
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, Above code just an example. I use `Array.length` in real case. Thanks for your CSS solution.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to what [jom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53975536/3917320) said: I'd rather use `v-if` than `v-show`, because as the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show) say:

> prefer `v-show` if you need to toggle something very often, and prefer `v-if` if the condition is unlikely to change at runtime.

Since you do not want to toggle the comma at any point, just don't render it at all :)

Answer (score 2):

Another addition to what has already been said. Inverting the order makes it easier to avoid the unneded comma (you always skip the first one, instead of need to take care of the array length)

```
<div v-for="(text, index) in ['vue', 'react', 'JQuery']"
     :key="text">
  <span v-if="index !== 0">,&nbsp;</span>
   <router-link tag="a">
    {{ text }}
  </router-link>
</div>
```